# can not retrieve data from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, c3p0

I can not retrieve data from db in sql server.

I use the c3p0 as the pool,this is the c3p0.properties:

```
c3p0.user=test
c3p0.password=123456
c3p0.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx:1433;databaseName=TIMDB;SelectMethod=cursor
c3p0.driverClass=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
c3p0.maxPoolSize=15
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin=true
c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=3600
```

In the sql server,I have create a new user named test,and its default db is TIMDB,the server roles is public,and this is the user mapping:
[image]

But when I start the application,I can get nothing.

From the log created by log4j,I can get the sql used to retrieve data,but if I copy the sql to the sql management stutio and create a new query,I can retrieve some data.

I wonder why?

Comment: Please show some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: sql is something like :select logtime,dn,dh from Mean_5Min where logtime between '2011-12-12 00:00:00' and '2011-12-13 00:00:00'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a permissions problem to me. If the generated SQl runs when you use it in management studio (i.e under your user account) then you know the code is good. What access have you given the user "test" from your post I see "user mapping: enter image description here"? he will need at least db_datareader and possibly more depending on what code is generated.

You could also try logging on to SQL Management studio under your "test" user and see if you can execute the code. That will eliminate the possibility that its something wrong with your application/network.

Comment: Did you also try logging into SQL management studio as your test user? If when logged in as him the SQL will execute you know the SQL is good and test has suitable permissions. Otherwise depending on the SQL he may need to have further permissions. Try db_owner if that fixes it you can then try narrowing down to the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Yes,I logged in the studio as test, And I can execute the sql.

Comment: I would say perhaps its not permissions then. How about network connectivity? Can the application definitely connect to the SQL server? Correct ports open etc. Perhaps something silly like a firewall issue.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply, I am to stupid!!!!  I just forget to set the ipall-tcp port to 1433,now it works. But I also wonder why the c3p0 does not tell me the connectivity is bad?